# How to prevent user from drop column in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, alter-table, sql-grant

I have an existing user with all privileges on a specific database. The user was created like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_db.* TO 'tester1'@'%%'
```

However, I want to restrict this user from dropping any table and any column of the database. I can revoke the **drop table** privilege from the user but i cannot revoke the **alter table** privilege because he should still be able to add new column. Is there a way to prevent this user from dropping any column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, MySQL does not have a distinct privilege for dropping a column. If the user has the ALTER privilege, they can both add or drop a column.

Comment: Thank you, i was going through the mysql doc and i could not find it either